# Product prices disappeared in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Product prices has been hidden and not more available to see. I'm using Woocommerce 3.02 in wordpress 4.7.3 . In catalog and product view prices are disappered but in checkout pages everything's fine.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: There's no way for us to answer this. It depends on your site's setup. You can take some basic debugging procedures, such as switch to a default theme, disable other plugins, turn on `WP_DEBUG` etc. Good luck.

Comment: Please confirm it is theme issue by switching the theme

Comment: It is not theme issue, I changed the theme but the problem does't solved..!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by my self..! 
Just deactive Woocommerce currency switcher plugin...